# Unable to assign the delegate to UITextField as it is in in Tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a table view. In that I am creating the `UITextField` dynamically.
But I am not able to fire the events in it.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell",for: indexPath) as! DynamicTableCell

        var dynamicTxtField1: UITextField = UITextField()
        dynamicTxtField1.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        dynamicTxtField1.rightViewMode = .always
        dynamicTxtField1.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        dynamicTxtField1.clipsToBounds = true
        dynamicTxtField1.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        // Here i am not able to assign the 
        //Error in this line // dynamicTxtField1.delegate = self 

        // Here object "self" is referring to the view. Because of this i am not able to fire any events of the UITextField 
        cell.addSubview(dynamicTxtField1)
}
```

Please suggest how to assign the delegate to the UITextField in this scenario so that I can fire an event to show a view to pick some values from it.

The error is:

> "Cannot assign the value of ViewName(classname) to type UITextFieldDelegate"

on the line:

```
dynamicTxtField1.delegate = self
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Does your `self` conform to `UITextFieldDelegate`?

Comment: When posting a question about an error, you need to include the complete and exact error message in your question.

Comment: Error is "Cannot assign the value of ViewName(classname) to type UITextFieldDelegate".
Self is not referring to UITextFieldDelegate that is what the problem is. What should i do now?

Comment: I made a mistake of adding UiTextViewDelegate instead of UiTextFieldDelegate. But i have corrected it . Still the events are not fired. dynamicTxtField1.addTarget(self, action: "ButtonPressed", for: UIControlEvents.touchDown) Will this work for a UITextField?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oz6CO.png)You should create your `textField` in your cell's subclass then modify its attributes in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Does your class implement `UITextFieldDelegate`?

EDIT: try this

```
        textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.textfieldDidchange(_:)), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
        cell.contentView.addSubview(textField)
```

and here is the method

```
func textfieldDidchange(textField: UITextField) {
//your code
```

}

Comment: I made a mistake of adding UiTextViewDelegate instead of UiTextFieldDelegate. But i have corrected it . Still the events are not fired.
     dynamicTxtField1.addTarget(self, action: "ButtonPressed", for: UIControlEvents.touchDown)
Will this work for a UITextField?????

Comment: Of you want to call a method each time you write a letter you need your own method and use .ValueChanged. UITextFieldDelegate does not handle it.

Comment: Can you please give me an example how to write it?
I want the method on Tap . Because i want to go to another view to show a table view as soon as user taps on the textField

Comment: Hi Mat,
I tried the way you mentioned. Here is my code.
dynamicTxtField1.addTarget(self, action: Selector(DynamicSuperView.textFieldChanged(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)


 func textFieldChanged(textField: UITextField) {
        print("TextField Changed!!!!!!!!!!!!")
    }

It throws an error saying textFieldChanged is not a member of this class

Comment: It works? Is DynamicSuperView a UIViewController?

Comment: Its not working. Yes it is a UIViewController. If you can see the intellisense  will strikeout the method we have created. I have edited the post with link to the error message. I don't think you will be able to see the strike off image is it is pending peer review.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/oz6CO.png

Comment: Check again my edit and try this code ty

Comment: Still no luck. It still says textFieldChanged is not a member

Comment: I changed my code to
dynamicTxtField1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(DynamicSuperView.textFieldChanged(textField:)),
                                for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)   
Now its not giving the compilation error but it is not executing the textFiledChanged function

Comment: textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onTextChange), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)

This solved the problem!!!!!